# issue with subtracting datetime types in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have been looking around, and I am sure the answer is right in front of me, but I am using the datetime for the first time and had a question. So short version is I have a script that reads a csv and looks for start and stop times for yard moves. I need to take those times and subtract them to see how long it took. I am not sure if using strptime is the right way to go about it or not. I am also confused as to why I can not subtract the stop_time and start_time from each other even though they are datetime.datetime types.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date

start_time = '0'
stop_time ='0'
trailer = '0'

t_time = open('move_times.csv')
t_time_reader = csv.reader(t_time, delimiter=',')

for i in t_time_reader:
    if i[2] == 'HOSTLER_COMPLETE':
        stop_time = date(datetime.strptime(i[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        trailer = i[11]
    elif i[2] == 'HOSTLER_START' and i[11] == trailer:
        start_time = date(datetime.strptime(i[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    
    print(stop_time - start_time)
```

Comment: with Python 3.7+, you can simplify to `datetime.fromisoformat(i[4]).date()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that on the first iteration at least one of `start_time` and `stop_time` will necessarily be the string `'0'`.

Consider the *first* iteration of the loop. `start_time == stop_time == '0'`, because you set them to this string before the loop.

Then, this `if` statement is executed:

```
if i[2] == 'HOSTLER_COMPLETE':
    stop_time = date(datetime.strptime(i[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    trailer = i[11]
elif i[2] == 'HOSTLER_START' and i[11] == trailer:
    start_time = date(datetime.strptime(i[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Here are the possible scenarios:

1. `(i[2] == 'HOSTLER_COMPLETE') is True`, so the first branch is taken. Then:

   - `stop_time` becomes a valid date
   - `start_time` remains equal to the string `'0'`
2. *OR* `(i[2] == 'HOSTLER_START' and i[11] == trailer) is True`, so the second branch is taken. Then:

   - `start_time` becomes a valid date
   - `stop_time` remains equal to the string `'0'`
3. *OR* neither branch is taken, since there's no explicit `else` branch. Then:

   - `start_time` remains equal to the string `'0'`
   - `stop_time` remains equal to the string `'0'`

Thus, after the `if` statement, at least one of `start_time` and `stop_time` will necessarily equal `'0'`.

Subtracting anything from a string is an error (as is subtracting a string from anything), so `print(stop_time - start_time)` fails. Thus, the first iteration of the loop fails, dragging along the entire program.